# Kernel and Image of 3 space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, random-matrices

nd the dimensions of $\operatorname{Im}(A)$ and $\ker(A)$, and find their bases for
the linear transformation $A$ on 
$\Bbb R^{3}$ defined by
$A(x, y, z) = (x − 2z, y + z, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of $A$ is the subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that gets mapped to the zero vector. So if $(x,y,z)\in\mathrm{ker}(A)$, it satisfies

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x-2z=0,\\
y+z=0.
\end{array}\right.$$

These two equations define a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ along the direction $(x,y,z)\propto$ $(2,-1,1)$. So we have

$$\mathrm{ker}(A)=\{(2t,-t,t)_{\,}|_{\,}t\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

The image of $A$ is the range of values that $(x-2z,y+z,0)$ can take, with arbitrary $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$. So $\,x-2z\,$ and $\,y+z\,$ are independent and can take all numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore

$$\mathrm{Im}(A)=\{(u,v,0)_{\,}|_{\,}u,v\in\mathbb{R}\}.$$

This problem shows that the kernel and image need not be orthogonal complements in general. All we know is $\,\dim\,\mathrm{ker}(A)+\dim\,\mathrm{Im}(A)=3\,$ for a general linear transformation $A\,$ over $\,\mathbb{R}^3$, which is because $\,\mathbb{R}^3=\mathrm{ker}(A)\oplus\mathrm{Im}(A)\,$ can be written as their direct sum.